# Input{xxx} : file not found

Tags: input, external-files

I'm using TexMaker and MikTex, and I created a folder called "first" where i put the .tex file and another file called xxx.txt. Now I want to import the file into latex by saying \input{xxx} and everytime and error occures saying: xxx.tex not found. I tryed with TexEditor and the same problem occures. Shouldn't it be xxx.txt not found? How can I manage with this error?

Comment: use `\input{xxx.txt}`  the default extension is `tex`  (or follow the normal convention and call your file `xxx.tex`)

Comment: use `\input{xxx.txt}`. If there is no extension (and the file is not found without extension) LaTeX will try `xxx.tex`. As you mention the files extension is `.txt` so you have to explicitly specify the extension when it is not `.tex`

Comment: I tryed but the problem still occures

Comment: Is the main tex file located in the directory "first" or in its parent directory? Please advise.

Comment: the main tex file is in the same directory of the txt file, no parent directories, only two files in a folder.